# Rails 3 - variable available in all controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I need to have a variable, that will be available in all controllers. For example, I tried something like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  @test = 'test string'
  ...
end
```

and if I tried to show the content of **@test** in `application.html.erb`, so I got the empty result.

One possibility is store the string to `session`, but this way I would like to use only as the latest possibility...

So I would like to ask you - exist in Rails any elegant way, how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `before_filter` to set the variable:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_test

  def set_test
    @test = 'test string'
  end
end
```

With this you *can* use `@test` in application.html.erb.